# Getting Coordinates of Embedded PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, pdf

I would like to embed a PDF in a webpage. When a user clicks on a certain coordinate within the embedded PDF, I would like to know what coordinate it corresponds to with respect to the PDF (and not the browser window). I will then plan on inserting text into the PDF server side so that a user can click on a portion of a PDF and add text to it through the webpage.

Does anybody know of any JS or other solutions to do this? I am using Django for the website.

Comment: If you are trying to create an online pdf editor, this might be harder than you think - unless you already know it is going to be really, really, really hard.

Comment: It's not supposed to be comprehensive. It's mostly to allow a user to fill in the blank fields of a PDF form.

Comment: I have never tried to do this, but perhaps you can cook something up using `pdf.js` (esp if your pdf contains a fillable form)

Comment: how did this go Matt?